# Intraweb - web application - users sessions

Tags: delphi, session, intraweb

Today I started to write my first web application and I can't pass one step.
Everything works almost fine... I can connect to the server and open website. Problem is when I open browser and type the same address on the second pc, then I get te same data as on the first one.

Detailed...
Application has two forms, first is for login, and second one is for receiving data.
When I login on the first pc and second form shows up, and then I open browser and put the address of the server on the second pc, I see the second form after login from first pc.

What I should do in this case? I tried to find the solution in the net, but I couldn't :(

Comment: Please provide your code. It is hard to guess what you did wrong, without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Delphi IDE after XE3 (including) and using the IntraWeb edition that comes with Delphi you must upgrade in order to have it working correctly. It is free, and more information can be obtained here:
[http://atozed.com/IntraWeb/Download/FreeKeyRequest.EN.aspx|](http://atozed.com/IntraWeb/Download/FreeKeyRequest.EN.aspx)

After upgrading (if this is your case) I suggest you to take a look at one of the IntraWeb demos, here:
https://iwdemos.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

There is a demo named Features that shows you exactly how to create a multi form application. To be honest, I work with IntraWeb for a long time and I've never seen that. Unless you are using some global var to hold your "current" active form. Have in mind that IntraWeb is a fully multithreaded application and global vars should not be used, unless you have some mechanism protecting concurrent access (but you should get rid of them and use ServerController properties instead).

Answer (score 0):

Thnks for your quick reply.
I work with Delphi from some time, but I never used Intraweb, I worked with ComPort and IP works for I/O devices. I have XE7 and I upgraded Intraweb to 14.0.52.

I can't find a good file exchange server to put my application for sharing with you. If I find somethin I will post it below.

You can check the code and other settings of my simply project. I put the web application inside the link below, it is without the .exe file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/75zurcew0zr363x/Project1.rar?dl=0

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this should be comment to Alexandre's answer.. please don't post responses as answer's to questions :)

Comment: You are calling TIWForm2.SetAsMainForm in the OnShow event handler. This method should not be called like that. SetAsMainForm() should only be called ONCE in the whole application life cycle. This method tells IntraWeb which is your application main form (in Desktop Delphi, you set the main form implicitly when you create the first form).
The main form is the active form when the application starts. If you need to have some dynamic main form (depending on some external factors), then you have to use the associated ServerController event.
What's your intention there?